# Help with $wpdb on custom code

Tags: database, wpdb

So i'm trying to implement some custom doing a SELECT to a table i created.

I'm using the following:

```
global $wpdb;
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpjk_vuln WHERE IDuser = " . um_profile_id());

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
  echo $fivesdraft->IDprogram;
}
```

When i open the page where the IDprogram should be displayed it isn't, not sure why.

**BUT**, if i add an echo with the query, bellow the code:

```
global $wpdb;

echo "SELECT * FROM wpjk_vuln WHERE IDuser = " . um_profile_id();

$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpjk_vuln WHERE IDuser = " . um_profile_id());

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
  echo $fivesdraft->IDprogram;
}
```

The page will display the IDprogram, it's just strange. I already hardcoded the um_profile_id() value and it happens the same thing.

Comment: Can you echo anything else from within the foreach to make sure the code is executing up to that point?

Answer (score 0):

If the `IDuser` field is an integer, try:

```
$um_profile_id = um_profile_id();

$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wpjk_vuln WHERE IDuser = $um_profile_id");
```